# Install tensorflow on windows

Tags: tensorflow, windows-10

I have windows 10(64 bit) and installed python 3.6. Now, when I type

`pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow`

as per tensorflow website in python, I get

> File "stdin", line 1
>       pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow                SyntaxError: invalid syntax

with `^` symbol below `install`. I'm facing problem in the installation. What's the issue?

Comment: Do you have also 64bit version of Python?

Comment: Also, how did you install python? Via Anaconda or other?

Comment: Are you acutally typing this into a python interpreter, since that would print exactly that error message?
This is not valid python code, and is not intended to be python code.
The line is for a shell, like bash, zsh, sh, or rather cmd or PowerShell for windows.

Comment: I have python 3.6. This I have checked from other similar question asked. I have installed python as well as Anaconda through the tensorflow website link. I executed this in cmd and powershell as well but with error " 'pip3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file". Both python and anaconda folder are in C drive i.e. "C:\python 3.6" and "C:\Anaconda".